# How do I to make Material UI `<Pagination>` control respect dark mode?

Tags: next.js, material-ui, pagination, darkmode

I am using a ` tag from Material-UI in my website.

The control works great, but it doesn't adapt to dark mode, so I get this:

[image]

Tag looks like this:

```
  <Pagination
    count={Math.ceil(blogProps.totalPosts / POSTS_PER_PAGE)} // Calculate the total number of pages
    page={currentPage}
    onChange={handlePageChange}
    showFirstButton
    showLastButton
    color="primary"
    sx={{ p: 3, mx: "auto" }}
  />
```

Theme is quite simple:

```
import { extendTheme } from "@mui/joy/styles";

const theme = extendTheme({
  fontFamily: {
    body: "'Public Sans', var(--joy-fontFamily-fallback)",
  },
});

export default theme;
```

And the code for my dark/light mode:

```
import { useColorScheme } from "@mui/joy/styles";
import IconButton from "@mui/joy/IconButton";
import * as React from "react";
import LightModeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LightMode";
import DarkModeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DarkMode";

export default function ModeButton() {
  const { mode, setMode } = useColorScheme();
  const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) {
    // to avoid layout shift, render a placeholder button
    return (
      <IconButton
        variant="plain"
        color="neutral"
        sx={{ width: 60 }}
        aria-label="Toggle light and dark mode"
      />
    );
  }
  return (
    <IconButton
      variant="plain"
      color="neutral"
      aria-label="Toggle light and dark mode"
      onClick={() => setMode(mode === "dark" ? "light" : "dark")}
    >
      {mode === "dark" ? <LightModeIcon /> : <DarkModeIcon />}
    </IconButton>
  );
}
```

How do I get the `<Pagination>` tag to honor the theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is to carefully and precisely follow all the instructions found on this page:

https://mui.com/joy-ui/guides/using-joy-ui-and-material-ui-together/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried useTheme hook?

```
const theme = useTheme(); // Access the theme

  return (
    <Pagination
      count={Math.ceil(blogProps.totalPosts / POSTS_PER_PAGE)}
      page={currentPage}
      onChange={handlePageChange}
      showFirstButton
      showLastButton
      color={theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "secondary" : "primary"} // Set color based on theme
      sx={{ p: 3, mx: "auto" }}
    />
  );
```

It is based on the theme's mode. If the mode is "dark", it uses the "secondary" color; otherwise, it uses the "primary" color.

Here is the github link has more example how to use use **theme.palette.mode**

https://github.com/search?q=theme.palette.mode&type=code

Comment: This is helpful, and I was sure it was going to work, but both the 'primary' and 'secondary' colors are not useful in darkmode.  This is very strange.

Answer (score -3):

To make a Material-UI `<Pagination>` control respect dark mode, you can follow these general steps:

1. **Use the `theme` Object:**

   Material-UI's `theme` object can be used to customize the styling of components including `<Pagination>`. You can define different styles for light and dark modes within the theme.
2. **Use the `palette` Section:**

   Inside the `theme` object, there's a `palette` section which holds color definitions for different aspects of the UI. You can define colors for text, background, primary, secondary, and more. You'll want to focus on the colors used by `<Pagination>`.
3. **Set Colors for Light and Dark Modes:**

   In the `palette` section, define colors for both light and dark modes. You can set the background and text colors based on your design preferences.
4. **Use the `createTheme` Function:**

   Use the `createTheme` function from Material-UI to create your custom theme. This function will combine your customizations with the default Material-UI theme.
5. **Apply the Theme to Your App:**

   Apply the theme you've created to your app. This might involve using the `ThemeProvider` component from Material-UI to wrap your app components, ensuring they use the theme's styling.

Here's an example of how you might set up your theme to make `<Pagination>` respect dark mode:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark', // Set to 'dark' for dark mode, 'light' for light mode
    primary: {
      main: '#ffffff', // Define the primary color for Pagination in dark mode
    },
    background: {
      paper: '#121212', // Define the background color for Pagination in dark mode
    },
  },
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* Your app components */}
      <Pagination count={10} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In this example, I've shown a basic way to set up a dark mode theme using Material-UI's `createTheme` function and applying it to your app components. You can adjust the colors and styles to match your desired dark mode appearance.

Comment: I find it sad that it is obvious to me that this was generated by AI....

Comment: Looks like it's generated by ChatGPT